# PageViewController doesnt work on Swift 2.0

Tags: swift, null, swift2, ios9

I have application that works well on ios8. However after updating everything to ios9 I am having problem with nill values. I cant figure out what value is nil. Here is the code:

```
func resetToChosenPage(index: Int!) {
    /* Getting the page View controller */
    pageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageViewController") as! UIPageViewController
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self

    pageContentViewController = self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)

    if pageContentViewController != nil {
    self.pageViewController.setViewControllers([pageContentViewController], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    /* We are substracting 30 because we have a start again button whose height is 30*/
    self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.height , self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height - 30)
    self.addChildViewController(pageViewController)
    self.view.addSubview(pageViewController.view)
    self.pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

}

func viewControllerAtIndex(index : Int) -> UIViewController? {


    if((dataArray.count == 0) || (index >= dataArray.count)) {
        return nil
    }
    let pageContentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SingleArticleViewController") as! SingleArticleViewController

    self.delegate = pageContentViewController
    pageContentViewController.delegate = self
  //  pageContentViewController.delegateWebView = self

    pageContentViewController.singleArticleIndex = index
    pageContentViewController.categoryID = categoryID
    pageContentViewController.dateOfPub = dataArray[index].pubDate
    pageContentViewController.category = dataArray[index].category
    pageContentViewController.newsTitle = dataArray[index].pageTitle
    pageContentViewController.videoLink = dataArray[index].videoLink
    return pageContentViewController
}
```

One line self.pageViewController.SetViewControllers([pageContentViewController]... I have error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". The fact is this code works well on ios8. I checked and could not find nil values. Moreover, I checked all identifiers of storyboard but they are correct. Guys, what can be a problem if this code works on ios8?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest try changing the `if` clause that wraps the `setViewControllers:` call so that it explicitly checks for both the pageContentViewController and the pageViewController:

```
if let pageVC = self.pageViewController, let contentVC = self.pageContentViewController {
    pageVC.setViewControllers([contentVC], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

As a general thing, I would try to avoid using Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals (like that Int! in your `resetToChosenPage:` method. As they lead to these 'unexpectedly found nil' errors.

Also, since your `resetToChosenPage:` method doesn't check if the pageViewController has already been instantiated, calling it multiple times will result in many instances of the PageViewController being instantiated and piled on top of each other. Which is probably not what you want.

Comment: I check both of them to nil value. Pageviewcontroller and PageContentViewController are not nil! I am thinking about your other claim, that we can not initiate it multiple times. How to avoid that? So, I must write code like if pageviewcontroller is nil instantiate it, if not dont do that?